# python matplotlib scatter plot colors error

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot with x and y grid where every point gets a color by a preassigned value:

```
{x: 1, y: 2, value: n}
```

I have a list of x and y and another list for the values, tried using this:

```
# make range of x(0 - 359) and y(-90 - 90)
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(0, 360), range(-90, 90))
colors = [a very long list (64800 values, one for each point)]
print(colors)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

**Errors:**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 158, in to_rgba
>     rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
> KeyError: (1.0986122886681098, None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4210, in scatter
>     colors = mcolors.to_rgba_array(c)
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 259, in to_rgba_array
>     result[i] = to_rgba(cc, alpha)
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 160, in to_rgba
>     rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 211, in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle
>     raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
> ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 1.0986122886681098
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/amit neumark/Documents/עמית/alpha/grbs data/grbs/find_burst_location.py", line 168, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "C:/Users/amit neumark/Documents/עמית/alpha/grbs data/grbs/find_burst_location.py", line 161, in main
>     ra2, dec2 = chi_square(model, relations)
>   File "C:/Users/amit neumark/Documents/עמית/alpha/grbs data/grbs/find_burst_location.py", line 33, in chi_square
>     create_plot(sums)
>   File "C:/Users/amit neumark/Documents/עמית/alpha/grbs data/grbs/find_burst_location.py", line 134, in create_plot
>     plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2793, in scatter
>     verts=verts, edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1785, in inner
>     return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4223, in scatter
>     .format(nc=n_elem, xs=x.size, ys=y.size)
> ValueError: 'c' argument has 64800 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 64800, 'y' with size 64800.
> ```

Comment: We'd need to know what values are in the color list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `x` and `y` data and not in the colors `c` parameter. Your x and y is currently a 2d array (meshgrid). It should be a list of positions. One way to do so is to flatten your 2d meshgrids to get a 1-d array. The one to one correspondence between x and y data points will be maintained. The meshgrids work normally for scatter 3d plots.

I am choosing some random colors to provide a solution.

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(0, 360), range(-90, 90))
colors = np.random.random(360*180)
plt.scatter(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), c=colors)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to plot using something like `imshow` or `pcolormesh`. This creates a "heatmap" across a grid of x,y coordinates. The x,y meshgrid is optional for these functions.

```
colors = np.arange(64800)

plt.pcolormesh(colors.reshape(360, 180).T)
# OR #
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(0, 360), range(-90, 90))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, colors.reshape(360, 180).T)
```

[image]

You should pay attention to how you reshape `colors`. You can fill either by rows or by columns. The default is by rows (last axis). This is also important to note in the other answer as you flatten your meshgrid.